# Is there a way to retrieve the current relative url in Protractor?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, e2e-testing

I'm starting to test an Angular2 project and I want to retrieve the URL of the browser in some tests to check that redirections are made correctly.

The problem is that the only method I can see in the API to retrieve the current URL is [webdriver.WebDriver.getCurrentUrl](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.getCurrentUrl), but it returns the absolute path. This can be a pain if for some reason you change the testing port or hostname in the future. Is there any way to retrieve only the relative URL like you can do with [browser.get](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.get)? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you want to get , for example, `questions/42695591/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-the-current-relative-url-in-protractor#42695591` from `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42695591/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-the-current-relative-url-in-protractor#42695591`?

Comment: Yes @Andersson , that's my question!

Comment: There is no reason to go through the extra work splicing the URL in my opinion. You should designate a `baseUrl: 'localhost:8045`' in your protractor.conf.js file and then for your assertion use `expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toBe(browser.baseUrl+ '/test');` this should make your tests usable in multiple environments.

Comment: Hi @sonhu , I haven't seen this answer before. This is what I was searching for, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To keep things simple - To handle future changes to host & port, you can just do this.

`expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain("/some/path/resource");`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that there is built-in method for same.

Suppose there is an `URL`, for example,

```
http://example.com/some/path/resource
```

Just as last resort you can use below code

```
browser.executeScript("return '/' + window.location.href.split('/').slice(3).join('/');")
```

to get just

```
/some/path/resource
```

or

```
browser.executeScript("return window.location.href.split('/')[window.location.href.split('/').length -1];")
```

to get

```
resource
```